# Error while executing soap request on ws security with cxf interceptor

Tags: web-services, cxf, soapui, ws-security, wss4j

I have developed a service in top down approach and it is working fine using apache cxf. Now I am trying to add basic authentication to the service. I have configured the server call back handler and spring bean (cxf-servlet.xml) as per the apache cxf documentation. But still
I am getting below error executing a soap request on SOAP UI.

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-14"><wsu:Created>2017-01-20T13:54:07Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2017-01-20T14:27:27Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp>
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-13">
<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">vPFjyEznvPB8HkWDOoL7dw==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2017-01-20T13:54:07.244Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Below is the my servercallback handler part.

```
<bean id="myPasswordCallback"
        class="com.firstbest.webservice.ofacimpl.ServerPasswordCallback" />
    <jaxws:endpoint publish="true" id="ofacid"
        implementor="com.firstbest.webservice.ofacimpl.OfacInquirySearchImpl"
        address="/PerformOFACValidationWS">
        <jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                        <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                            <ref bean="myPasswordCallback" />
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

I have tried different solution regarding this on net. But couldn't help me much.

Below is the error:-

> WARNING: Interceptor for
>   {http://sdawweaid1.gc.win-na.com/QBE_OFAC/Producer/BridgerInsight/WS/executeIService_SearchWS}OfacInquirySearchImplService#{http://sdawweaid1.gc.win-na.com/QBE_OFAC/Producer/BridgerInsight/WS/executeIService_SearchWS}executeIService_Search
>   has thrown exception, unwinding now
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was
>   encountered when verifying the message    at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: An error
>   was discovered processing the  header  at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.checkActions(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:361)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInIntercept

Comment: Your configuration seems ok. Could you remove nonce and timestamp just to check if it has any effect?

Comment: I just tried taking out timestamp and nonce. But output still remains same. I have missed two lines of error log...                                           'Jan 20, 2017 8:18:27 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor checkActions
WARNING: Security processing failed (actions mismatch)'

Comment: That error usually means "action" is misconfigured, but I can't see any error

Comment: Thanks. I have removed timestamp and restarted the soap ui. it worked fine.